# Unable to register users firebase: A network error (such as a timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to register users using Firebase email and password authentication. I have previously had it working by following and reading multiple tutorials. However, it is now failing to register at all. I've checked all the gradle files and permissions and nothing seems to be missing.

It automatically goes to the else statement and prints a toast message. This is line

```
else
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Could Not Register. Please Check Your Details Again And Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I can't see what has changed to make it fail. Their is a correctly formatted email and password being sent to the createUserWithEmailAndPassword method as well.

```
private void registerUser() {
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        // email is too short
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter An Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // password to short
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter A Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            //if validation is ok, show progress bar
            progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User Please Wait");
            progressDialog.show();

            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateProfileActivity.class));
                            } else if (!task.isSuccessful() && password.length() < 6){
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Could Not Register. Passwords much be at least 6 characters ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Could Not Register. Please Check Your Details Again And Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateProfileActivity.class));
        }

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailLogin);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordLogin);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        textViewSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignIn);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerUser();
            }
        });

        textViewSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Comment: No i'm getting no error at all. I've inserted multiple breakpoints as well, no error is occurring. The app works fine, it doesn't break, it just jumps to the else statement and doesn't register

Comment: have you enabled email/password in the firebase Console @ Craig ?

Comment: What does `task.getException()` return?

Comment: Yes i've enabled the email/password on firebase. I get User Authentication Failed: A network error (such as a timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. Seems like it's a connection error to firebase im experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Could Not Register. Please Check Your Details Again And Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

into this:

```
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Authentication Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to know what the problem might be.

According to the error, you need to check if google play services is running, it is recommended to test the app on a physical device not an emulator or download google play service on an emulator as not all of them has it.

Comment: I've just changed that line and it now says, User Authentication Failed: A network error (such as a timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. Seems like it's a connection error to firebase im experiencing.  Thanks

Comment: is google play service running? Try this on a physical device not on an emulator @CraigMartin

Comment: I've been running it off my phone. I'll check the google play services thank you

Comment: the firebase dependencies need to be at 11.8.0

Comment: yes he needs to update both the dependencies and google play service

Comment: The dependencies where all ok, it was google play services needed updating. Updated and restarted my device and it's all working fine again. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I have latest Google Play Services on my devices, but got this error when try use firebase auth service to login in Ionic App.